# Is there any school or institution dedicated to teaching Jhana?

Tags: theravada, teaching, jhana

Is there any school or institution dedicated to teaching Jhana?

Teaching "Jhana" means:

1. Accepting students to learn only about Jhana
2. Proper courses and guidelines for student: step by step, from first Rupa Jhana to Four Arupa Jhanas, in Theravada Buddhist teachings (see [Dhyāna in Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhy%C4%81na_in_Buddhism))

It could be a monastery or public institution or school, which people can join by paying fees or free; but well disciplined and helping students to experience and acquire the capabilities to enter the state of various Jhanas above.

Are there any printed courses or lectures about entering Jhanas, published by such a school or institution (or by an author at least)?

Answer (score 4):

Ven. Pa-Auk Sayadaw teaches both Samatha and Vipassana meditation. First one develops Jhanas and then one can progress to Vipassana if wanted.

Here is a description from the website of [*Pa-Auk Forest Monastery*](http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/meditation.htm):

> "The meditation taught at Pa-Auk Tawya is based on the instructions by The Buddha as found in the Tipiṭaka (the Pāli Canon) and its commentaries.
>
> In brief, the main practice is to begin with Samatha (tranquility) meditation, which is to develop absorption concentration, also called jhāna. A yogi (meditator) is free to choose any of the forty Samatha subjects as taught by The Buddha. In Pa-Auk Tawya, most yogis develop jhāna with mindfulness-of-breathing (ānāpānassati).
>
> Having developed Samatha, the yogi may proceed to practise Vipassanā (insight) meditation".

Comment: Because nowadays we almost have only neyya-puggala, who must have jhana to be base of vipassana, so Pa-Auk teachers always taught like that. It is full steps of meditation teaching. Pa-Auk method, that use all of  pali cannons method, have to take continuously long time to progress, but it is very sure method to get magga&phala&nibbana.

Comment: you can see netti-pali and mahasatipatthanasutta-commentary for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Bhante Vimalaramsi is dedicated to teaching insight progress through jhana, following the original Pali suttas rather than the commentaries. He is the abbot of [Dhamma Sukha Meditation Center](http://www.dhammasukha.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Ajahn Brahm's group are dedicated to jhana. Try these links:

- [Mindfulness, Bliss, and Beyond - A Heditator's Handbook](http://www.dhammaloka.org.au/files/pdf/Ajahn_Brahm-Mindfulness_Bliss_and_Beyond-Chapters1-4.pdf) by Ajahn Brahm
- [Welcome to the Buddhist Society of Western Australia -
  Dhammaloka Centre](http://www.dhammaloka.org.au/)
- [Jhana Grove](http://cms.jhanagrove.org.au/about/)
- [Bodhinyana Monastery](http://cms.bodhinyana.org.au/)